# How to make floating action button consume click event?

Tags: java, android, material-design, floating-action-button

I am currently setting up a floating action button in my app i am making.
My problem is that when i click the button, the listview behind the button also receives the click event.
I need to make it so that the button consumes the entire click event.

I am using this library to create the button: https://github.com/FaizMalkani/FloatingActionButton

If someone could point me in the right direction regarding how to achieve this, it would be much appreciated.
I have included the xml layout i am using below.

Thanks
Corey :)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabbutton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:colour="@color/holo_red_light"
        app:drawable="@drawable/ic_content_new"

    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the implementation details of FloatingActionButton, but you can set a TouchListener and consume the event returning true from onTouch method. Something like this:

```
mFloatingActionButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return true; // consume the event
    }
});
```